# Multiple elements with the same class, get the text of only the clicked element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to post a value inside an anchor tag, but first I want to show the value inside the console to test if it works. I've got multiple elements that have the same class, and I get the text of that class, which means that whatever element I click with that class, it shows ALL values.

How can I make sure it only shows the clicked element?

My code:

```
<li class="active lidcat">
    <input type="radio" name="bedno" '.$checked.'>
    <a class="zoekvalue" href="'.$void.'">'.$ledeninfo['title'].'</a>
</li>

$( document ).ready(function() {
  $( ".lidcat" ).click(function() {
    var test = $(".zoekvalue").text();
    console.log(test);
  });
});
```

My list contains the following data:

```
Accountancy & Belastingadvies
Afslank en schoonheidsinstituut
Automatisering & ICT
Bakkerij
```

And this is what is returned in the console:

```
Accountancy & BelastingadviesAfslank en schoonheidsinstituutAutomatisering & ICTBakkerij
```

Comment: `var test = $(this).text();`

Comment: @JohnR Will it still get the text of the link? If I'm not mistaken, `this` points to the `li`

Comment: @JohnR This returns nothing

Comment: @Swellar Yes it points the `li`.

Comment: @twan https://jsfiddle.net/91efderu/ Check this.

Comment: @twan If you want the text of `.zoekvalue` alone means, you can go with `children()` to access it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your script as below.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $( ".lidcat" ).click(function() {
    var test = $(this).children(".zoekvalue").text();
    console.log(test);
  });
});
```

By clicking a tag

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
   $( ".zoekvalue" ).click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var test = $(this).text();
      console.log(test);
   });
});
```

Comment: This works thanks! Won't this give any issues for posting to a php script with ajax?

Comment: no it will not give any issues. Use a tag click event

Answer (score 2):

Use `find()` to get the link that is the child of the clicked `li`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".lidcat").click(function() {
    var test = $(this).find(".zoekvalue").text();
    console.log(test);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="active lidcat">
  <input type="radio" name="bedno">
  <a class="zoekvalue" href="'.$void.'">Some text</a>
</li>
<li class="active lidcat">
  <input type="radio" name="bedno">
  <a class="zoekvalue" href="'.$void.'">Some texts</a>
</li>
<li class="active lidcat">
  <input type="radio" name="bedno">
  <a class="zoekvalue" href="'.$void.'">Some textss</a>
</li>
<li class="active lidcat">
  <input type="radio" name="bedno">
  <a class="zoekvalue" href="'.$void.'">Some textsss</a>
</li>
<li class="active lidcat">
  <input type="radio" name="bedno">
  <a class="zoekvalue" href="'.$void.'">Some textsss</a>
</li>
```